# python: multiprocessing.Pipe and redirecting stdout

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe, dup2

I am using `multiprocessing` package to spawn a second process from which I would like to redirect stdout and stderr into the first process. I am using `multiprocessing.Pipe` object:

```
dup2(output_pipe.fileno(), 1)
```

Where `output_pipe` is an instance of `multiprocessing.Pipe`. However, when I try to read on the other end, it just hangs. I tried reading using `Pipe.recv_bytes` with a limit, but that raises an `OSError`. Is this possible at all or should I just switch to some lower level pipe functions?

Comment: Can you add a complete, runnable example that demonstrates your error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After experimenting in Python 2.7 I got this working example. With `os.dup2` pipe's file descriptor is copied to standard output file descriptor, and each `print` function ends up writing to a pipe.

```
import os
import multiprocessing


def tester_method(w):
    os.dup2(w.fileno(), 1)

    for i in range(3):
        print 'This is a message!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    r, w = multiprocessing.Pipe()

    reader = os.fdopen(r.fileno(), 'r')

    process = multiprocessing.Process(None, tester_method, 'TESTER', (w,))
    process.start()

    for i in range(3):
        print 'From pipe: %s' % reader.readline()

    reader.close()
    process.join()
```

Output:

```
From pipe: This is a message!

From pipe: This is a message!

From pipe: This is a message!
```

Comment: Hi, It indeed works, however when reading from pipe as: `r.recv()` it does not. Do you know why, or how to check (non blocking) if reader has anything to read?

Comment: @RadoslawGarbacz You must use `w.send` then, as per https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#Connection.recv.

Comment: getting this error - OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor for os.fdopen statement. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Note - Just now tried in Linux, this code works, whereas the same code is failing in Windows - OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: I tried it on Windows, it gave OSError: [Errno 6] The handle is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer works for the raw file descriptors, but this may be useful for using Pipe.send() and recv:

```
    class PipeTee(object):
        def __init__(self, pipe):
            self.pipe = pipe
            self.stdout = sys.stdout
            sys.stdout = self

        def write(self, data):
            self.stdout.write(data)
            self.pipe.send(data)

        def flush(self):
            self.stdout.flush()

        def __del__(self):
            sys.stdout = self.stdout
```

To use this, create the object in your multiprocess function, pass it the write side of `multiprocessing.Pipe`, and then use the read side on the parent process with `recv`, using `poll` to check if data exists.